# How can I make this testNG test dynamic but remain parallel

Tags: java, testng, testng-eclipse, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

```
public class FactoryTest {
    
    @Test  
    @Parameters("Row")
    public void run1(int row) throws MalformedURLException{           
        new Controller(row);
    }
    
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
  <test thread-count="2" name="factory test" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.FactoryTest">
             <methods>
                    <include name="run1">
                        <parameter name="Row"  value="1"/>
                    </include>                
                </methods></class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- OfficialTestName -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This is an example of one of the tests I need to run. I need it to run in parallel with other tests. So in the test `run1()` I create a `Controller(row)` which initiates the test and I pass a row number to it. I want to run `new Controller(1)` and `new Controller(2)` and `new Controller(3)`, etc all at the same time. I am able to do this if I change the java file to this:

```
public class OfficialTest {
    
    @Test    
    public void run1() throws MalformedURLException{           
        new Controller(1);
    }
    
    @Test    
    public void run2() throws MalformedURLException{           
        new Controller(2);
    }
    
    @Test    
    public void run3() throws MalformedURLException{           
        new Controller(3);
    }
    
    @Test    
    public void run4() throws MalformedURLException{           
        new Controller(4);
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("closing");
    }
}
```

but this isn't dynamic. I need to be able to run this using any range of number for the `row`. So I was thinking maybe I could generate an XML file that would take care of this but I still am not sure if it would even be able to run in parallel that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make dynamic parallel tests in testNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63512576/how-to-make-dynamic-parallel-tests-in-testng)

Comment: No it doesn't. that is also my question and no one answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with this:

```
public class ParallelTests 
{

    int row;
    
    @Parameters({"Row"})
    @BeforeMethod()
    public void setUp(int rowParam) throws MalformedURLException
    {           
       row = rowParam;
    }
    
    @Test
    public void RunTest() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException
    {
        new Controller(row);
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" name="BlogSuite" parallel="tests">
<test name="Test 1">
<parameter name="Row" value="1"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="Test 2">
<parameter name="Row" value="2"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
    <test name="Test 3">
<parameter name="Row" value="3"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
    <test name="Test 4">
<parameter name="Row" value="4"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
      <test name="Test 5">
<parameter name="Row" value="5"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  </suite>
```